# not able to save data in join table for has_many_through associations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have user, team and team_user model. team_use is joining model as a result of has_many through association between user and team. team_user has user_id and team_id from user and team tables. team has name and team_lead_id( which would a user from user table).

**Problem:**

When I create new team, I want to add users and team lead to team. A team can have multiple user but only one team lead. While creating team , user_id and team_id should be saved in team_user table. But this is not happening. I tried with following code in team_controller.rb:

```
def create
    @team = Team.new(params[:team])
      @user_team = TeamUser.new( { user_id: '@user.id', team_id: 'params[:team_id]' } )
      if @team.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Team has been created'
        redirect_to teams_path
      else
        flash[:alert] = 'Team not created'
        redirect_to teams_path
      end
  end
```

With `TeamUser.new( { user_id: '@user.id', team_id: 'params[:team_id]' } )` , I tried to create user and team entries in team_user table but failed.

Code is following.

**teams_controlller.rb**

```
class TeamsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authorize_admin!

  def index
    @teams = Team.all
    @team = Team.new
  end

  def new
    @team = Team.new
  end

  def create
    @team = Team.new(params[:team])
      @user_team = TeamUser.new( { user_id: '@user.id', team_id: 'params[:team_id]' } )
      if @team.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Team has been created'
        redirect_to teams_path
      else
        flash[:alert] = 'Team not created'
        redirect_to teams_path
      end
  end

  def show
    @team = Team.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @team = Team.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @team = Team.find(params[:id])
      if @team.update_attributes(params[:team])
        flash.notice = "Team #{@team.name} has been updated"
        redirect_to team_path
      else
        render 'edit'
      end
  end

  def destroy
    @team = Team.find(params[:id])
    @team.destroy
    redirect_to action:  'index'
  end

end
```

**team.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :roles,  through: :role_users
 has_many :role_users
 has_many :leaves
 serialize :role
 has_many :teams, through: :team_users
 before_save :make_array
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
  :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation,
  :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name, :is_admin, :contact_no, :birth_date,
  :joining_date, :is_active, :role, :is_manager, :user_code, :designation
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

   def active_for_authentication?
     super && is_active?
   end

  def make_array
   self.role.reject!(&:blank?) if self.role
  end

end
```

**team_user.rb**

```
class TeamUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team
  attr_accessible :team_id, :team_lead_id, :user_id
end
```

**team.rb**

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through: :team_users
  has_many :team_users
  attr_accessible :name, :team_lead_id
end
```

**_form.html.erb(team)**

```
<%= form_for @team do |f| %>
  <% @team.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>

  <div style=" margin-top:10px">
    <label> Team Name </label>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'text_field' %>
  </div>

  <label> Add Users </label>
  <%= select_tag "TeamUser[user_id]", options_from_collection_for_select( User.all, "id", "first_name"), :style => "width:270px; height:35px", :id => "drp_Books_Ill_Illustrations",
      :class => "leader MultiSelctdropdown Books_Illustrations" %>

   <label> Team Lead </label>
  <%= f.select(:team_lead_id, User.all.map { |u| [u.first_name, u.id] }) %>

  <div class=modal-footer>
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
    <%= f.submit "Create Team", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**schema.rb**

```
 create_table "team_users", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "team_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   :null => false
  end

  create_table "teams", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at",   :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   :null => false
    t.integer  "team_lead_id"
  end
```

I am able to create team with team_lead_id in team model but failed to save data in team_user team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's not being saved is that you call `new` instead of `create`. Besides, when you are trying to create `TeamUser` record, you don't know `@team.id` yet it's not saved at this time. But there's also other things that need to be fixed. First, your `new` action should look:

```
def new
  @team = Team.new
  @users = User.all
end
```

Now you don't need to call `User.all` twice in your view, which isn't very good practice. 
Now, the view:

```
  <%= form_for @team do |f| %>
  <% @team.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>

  <div style=" margin-top:10px">
    <label> Team Name </label>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :class => 'text_field' %>
  </div>

  <label> Add Users </label>
  <%= select_tag "users[]", options_from_collection_for_select( @users, :id, :first_name), :style => "width:270px; height:35px", :id => "drp_Books_Ill_Illustrations",
      :class => "leader MultiSelctdropdown Books_Illustrations", :multiple => true %>

   <label> Team Lead </label>
  <%= select_tag(:team_lead_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@users, :id, :first_name)) %>

  <div class=modal-footer>
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
    <%= f.submit "Create Team", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In your `create` action:

```
def create
  @team = Team.new(params[:team])
  team_lead = User.find(params[:team_lead_id])
  @team.team_lead = team_lead
  if @team.save
    users = User.where(:id => params[:users])
    users.each {|user| @team.users << user}
    flash[:notice] = 'Team has been created'
    redirect_to teams_path
  else
    flash[:alert] = 'Team not created'
    redirect_to teams_path
  end
end
```

And you should also update your `Team` model:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through: :team_users
  has_many :team_users
  belongs_to :team_lead, class_name: 'User'
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

Since you display form not only in `new` action, I advice you to make `before_filter` in your controller which would set variables needed for form:

```
before_filter :set_form_variables, only: [:new, :index] # everywhere the form is displayed
# ...
private
  def set_form_variables
    @team = Team.new
    @users = User.all
  end
```

Comment: hi @marek-lipka ,I tried with your code but I am getting ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in TeamsController#create

User(#89523760) expected, got NilClass(#74554310) ERROR.

Comment: I changed "new" with "create" in my existing code of controller. I got  entries in team_user table but still user_id and team_id are empty. FOllowing is result:-     irb(main):011:0> a = TeamUser.all
  TeamUser Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "team_users".* FROM "team_users" 
=> [#<TeamUser id: 1, team_id: 0, user_id: 0, team_lead_id: nil, created_at: "2013-06-27 18:07:24", updated_at: "2013-06-27 18:07:24">]

Comment: So you want to select one user to be team's leader and one user to add to team?

Comment: hi @marek-lipka, while creating team , I want to add one team lead using team_lead_id column in team table and also want to add multiple users to team. I have updated question with schema.rb file.

Comment: hi @marek-lipka, team_lead column is not in user table. Instead it is part of team table. You can check from my question, as you mention in Team model:- class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through: :team_users
  has_many :team_users
  belongs_to :team_lead, class_name: 'User'
  attr_accessible :name
end

Comment: I know it isn't. `class_name` option specifies class for relation. Since `Team`'s `team_lead` should be instance of `User` and it can't be inferred from the name of association, you need to specify `class_name` explictly. This code should work.

Comment: hi @marek-lipka, now I am trying with our code, but I am getting error   in _form.html.erb(team) which is following:- NoMethodError in Teams#index

Showing /home/vieenay/Desktop/merlin_vertis/app/views/teams/_form.html.erb where line #12 raised:

undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Error lies in following code of _form.html.erb:-   <%= select_tag "users[]", options_from_collection_for_select( @users, :id, :first_name), :style => "width:270px; height:35px", :id => "drp_Books_Ill_Illustrations",
      :class => "leader MultiSelctdropdown Books_Illustrations", :multiple => true %>

Comment: It's because you display form also in `index` action and `@users` instance variable is unset in this action. Wait a few minutes, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Done. Check this out, please.

Comment: hi @marek-lipka, even now I am getting following error:- ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TeamsController#create

Couldn't find User without an ID.

Comment: It might be due to  team_lead = User.find(params[:team_lead]) in teams.controller.rb . 1. We are trying to find team_lead from user table but there is no team_lead column in user table.2:- There is not team_lead coloumn in my project, you may mean team_lead_id. right ?

Comment: Yes, it's my mistake. Another update. :) You're right it should be `params[:team_lead_id]` in controller, you're not right about the reason. And the reason is that we pass `lead_id` in parameter called `team_lead_id`. If I wrote `select_tag :team_lead` in view, there would be also `params[:team_lead]` in controller.

Comment: hi @marek-lipka, It worked. I want one more suggestion from you that team_lead_id column should be in team or team_user table. Currently it is part of team table. When i create new team , team_id and user_id go to team_user table name(team) and team_lead_id go to team table. now I only save team_lead_id in team table and then how to fetch first name or last name of that team_lead_id.

Comment: hi @marek-lipka, With your code , now team_lead_id is saved in team_user table but it is nil. you can see from following query:- a = TeamUser.last
  TeamUser Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "team_users".* FROM "team_users" ORDER BY "team_users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<TeamUser id: 3, team_id: 10, user_id: 9, team_lead_id: nil, created_at: "2013-06-27 19:43:28", updated_at: "2013-06-27 19:43:28">

Comment: If `team` should have one leader, it should be in `teams` table. Since I made association `team_lead` in `team`, you can fetch all `team_lead`'s data from team with `team.team_lead`. It will return object of class `User`, representing `team_lead` record.

Comment: That's weird. Ok. try to enter sandbox console (with `rails c -s`) and create `Team` record by hand:

    `team = Team.new`, `team.team_lead = User.first` and `team.save`. Then call `team.reload` and check `team.team_lead_id`.

Comment: team_lead_id is saved in  Team table but not TeamUser table.As you can see:- c = Team.last
  Team Load (2.7ms)  SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" ORDER BY "teams"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<Team id: 11, name: "Bank of Broda", created_at: "2013-06-27 19:56:45", updated_at: "2013-06-27 19:56:45", team_lead_id: 17>

Comment: By doing, I am getting team_lead_id.I have attached results for your queries :- team.reload
  Team Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 12]]
=> #<Team id: 12, name: "Rohtak Team", created_at: "2013-06-27 20:03:09", updated_at: "2013-06-27 20:07:19", team_lead_id: 7>
irb(main):007:0> team.team_lead_id
=> 7

Comment: Ok. `team_lead_id` should not be in `team_users` table, only in `teams` table. You don't need this column in `team_users` table. Simply remove this column from this table.

Comment: Currently, team_lead-id column is part of Team table only. Please check from my question.

Comment: What if you get rid of `team_lead_id` in `team_users`' `attr_accessible`?

Comment: hi @marek-lipka, sorry I could not understand your last comment.

Comment: You have `attr_accessible :team_id, :team_lead_id, :user_id` in your `TeamUser` model. With your current implementation, you completely don't need this. Delete it and check if it solves your problem with `team_lead_id` in `TeamUser` instance.

Comment: No, TeamUser model only have attr_accessible :team_id, :user_id.Please check from my question. It is part of Team model:- class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through: :team_users
  has_many :team_users
  belongs_to :team_lead, class_name: 'User'
  attr_accessible :name, :team_lead_id
end

Comment: Are you sure? In your question you have line `attr_accessible :team_id, :team_lead_id, :user_id` in `TeamUser`, check again.

Comment: hi @marek-lipka, With your solution, I am not able to edit team. It throws following error:- NoMethodError in Teams#edit

Showing /home/vieenay/Desktop/merlin_vertis/app/views/teams/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class. Though edit method is in team controller.

Comment: @VSiingh Ensure that `@team` instance variable points object of `Team` class when the partial with form is evaluated.

Comment: hi @marek-lipka, @team instance variable is part of edit action in team controller and same instance variable in form to edit. but still it throws error like NoMethodError in Teams#edit and undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class. Main failure point here is that it does not understand @team variable in _form partial for edit.